# How to count the output of the console

Tags: c#, count, output

This is a Grading Marksheet code and I am looking for how the app may count how many times a string (e.g: Grade is A) has been repeated. Thank you!
This code sample is the part where I need to count the string from

```cs
if (p > 60 && p <= 80)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Grade is A");
}
if (p > 80 && p <= 100)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Grade is A++");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Declare a counter (var count = 0) and increment in the correct if statement (counter++)

Comment: Show us an example of the input and the desired output.

Comment: so the input will be like this
no. of roll: (number)
Score A:
Score B:
Score C:
The desired output would say how many students got (e.g: Grade A)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea would be to simply increase a integer variable for each time you print an A.

**Example with your Code as Base:**

```
// Use a Variable that you increase in value
// To see how many A were printed
int acount = 0;

// Is number bigger than 60 and smaller or equal to 80
if (p > 60 && p <= 80)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Grade is A");
    acount++;
}
// If the first statement is true the second can't be true anyway
// so use else if so it doesn't have to make usless checks

// Is number bigger than 80 and smaller or equal to 100
else if (p > 80 && p <= 100)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Grade is A++");
    acount++;
}
// Print out result
Console.WriteLine("A was printed: " + acount + " times");
Console.ReadLine();
```